# Graph plot 3D interpolating vertex data

Tags: graphics3d, color

I would like to plot a 3d graph given some data on vertices of the graph. I managed to color the vertices according to the data however, I would like the edge color to correspond to these values, like an interpolation I cannot find the correct function to do it properly in Mathematica. Here is an example

```
Npoints = 10;
DeltaL = 2/(Npoints - 1);
Pointsx = Range[-1, 1, DeltaL];
Pointsy = ConstantArray[0, Npoints];
Pointsz = ConstantArray[0, Npoints];
Points = {Pointsx, Pointsy, Pointsz};
Values = Table[i, {i, 1, Npoints, 1}];
AdjacentMatrix = 
  Transpose[
   Insert[IdentityMatrix[Npoints - 1], ConstantArray[0, Npoints - 1], 
    1]];

erf2[pts_, fromTo_, _] := Join[{ColorData["Rainbow"]@RandomReal[], Cylinder[pts, DeltaL/10]}]

  GraphPlot3D[AdjacentMatrix, EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf2, 
          VertexRenderingFunction -> ({ColorData["Rainbow"][
          Rescale[Values][[#2]]], Sphere[#1, DeltaL/8]} &), 
          VertexCoordinateRules -> Transpose[Points]]
```

This gives me
[image: example]

It is nearly what I'm looking for except that I would like to have the cylinders coloured according to the vertex colour (i.e. to replace `ColorData["Rainbow"]@RandomReal` in erf2 by a suitable function which I cannot find. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
erf2[pts_, v_, _] := 
 Tube[pts, .01, 
  VertexColors -> ((ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[values][[#]]]) & /@ 
     v)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working perfectly!